# how to delete variables instantiated by constructor

Tags: c#, class, object

```
public class Row
{
    //row
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public bool sortable { get; set; }
    public string classes { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }               
}

private static List<object> dataList = new List<object>()
{
    new Row() 
    { 
        name= "Milestones", 
        height= "3em", 
        sortable= false,
        classes= "gantt-row-milestone", 
        color= "#45607D",
    }

    new Row() 
    { 
        name= "Milestones", 
        height= "3em", 
        color= "#45607D",
    }
}
```

I am trying to create two objects with different number of variables 
and my problem is that I don't now how to delete or escape variables instantiated  by default (with 0 or null)

Comment: Where is the constructor you've mentioned? Also, why do you use a `List<Object>` instead of a `List<Row>`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete' and 'escape' variables?

Comment: You can't delete properties from a class. Why want you to do this?

Comment: do you want to remove variable or you just want to reset the property ?

Comment: "I am trying to create two objects with different number of variables" - then why not use two different classes?

Comment: @hpko: You may want to use `Inheritance`

Comment: Learn about OO basics: polymorphism and inheritance it what you need.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter I have other objects that use different class (Tasks) which I want to store in the same list

Comment: Note that [properties should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)s from an object. But you can design your classes as you need.

```
public class GenericRow
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public class DetailedRow : GenericRow
{
    public bool sortable { get; set; }
    public string classes { get; set; }
}
```

And instantiate your objects as following.

```
private static List<GenericRow> dataList = new List<GenericRow>()
{
    new DetailedRow () 
    { 
        name= "Milestones", 
        height= "3em", 
        sortable= false,
        classes= "gantt-row-milestone", 
        color= "#45607D",
    },
    new GenericRow() 
    { 
        name= "Milestones", 
        height= "3em", 
        color= "#45607D",
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `null` to indicate a 'deleted' property:

```
var row = (Row)dataList[0];
if (row.name == null)
    // name is deleted
else
    DoSomething(row.name);
```

For value types use `Nullable<>`:

```
public bool? sortable { get; set; }

if (row.sortable == null)
    // sortable is deleted
else
    DoSomething(row.sortable.Value);
```